# How to prove a matrix is invertible given a polynomial that annihilates it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

The question reads:

> Let $A\in M_{10}$, let $f(z)=z^{4}+11z^{3}-7z^{2}+5z+3$, and suppose $f(A)=0$.  Prove that $A$ is invertible and find a polynomial $g$ of degree $3$ or less such that $A^{-1}=g(A)$.

The chapter the question comes from covers the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem and minimal polynomials, but I don't see how either of those topics help to show that the inverse exists given a random polynomial.  I can find the polynomial $g$, but I don't see how to prove that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Since $A$ satisfies $f$ and the constant term of $f$ is nonzero, $A$ cannot have a $0$ eigenvalue.

Comment: If $f(0)\neq 0$ and $f(A)=0$, then $A\cdot(-f(0))^{-1}\cdot\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|_{x=A}=I$. Therefore, $(-f(0))^{-1}\cdot\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|_{x=A}=A^{-1}$

Comment: @saulspatz That makes sense.  I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 3):

From $f(A)=0$ we have $$-3I=A^4+11A^3-7A^2+5A = (A^3+11A^2-7A+5I)A.$$ Can you see what $A^{-1}$ must be?